# Using cfoot command

Tags: header-footer, fancyhdr

Here is my file

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\cfoot{abc}

\begin{document}

ab

\end{document}
```

As I understand from [this website](http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/Wiki/index.php/LaTeX:Packages), the `cfoot` command is supposed to produce a footer `abc`. But the file just has the page number `1` in the footer. What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to add

```
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}% to clear existing header/footer if you don't want it
\renewcommand\headrulewidth{0pt}
\cfoot{abc}
```

Answer (score 1):

An alternative to `fancyhdr` is the very modern
`scrlayer-scrpage` which can do really fancy stuff.

If you are planning to switch to a KOMA class, this is the way to
go.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\clearpairofpagestyles
\cfoot{abc}

\begin{document}
\blindtext
\end{document}
```